# PHP Use variables in an array with colons

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot seem to figure out how to work with variables in this array structure. I'm quite familiar with using associative arrays and using variable values in those, but a colon structure is something I've never seen before.

I need to swap out the "pid" values with a variable, rather than hard code. How can this be done?

```
$data = array('methods' => '
[{"method":"main_widget","params":{"pid":"703"}},
 {"method":"bottomline","params":{"pid":"703",
                  "link":"",
                  "skip_average_score":false}}
]', 
'app_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Comment: The value of `methods` is a JSON string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do something like `$data['methods'] = json_decode($data['methods'])` to convert the JSON to an object in PHP, or in this case an array of objects.

If you want to use it as an array, pass `true` as the second argument of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and it will return the parsed JSON string as an array, rather than an object.

The former way you could then iterate over `$data['methods']` as `object->variable` e.g.

```
foreach ($data['methods'] as $datum) {
  echo "method: $datum->method" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: That shows my extent of knowledge with JSON lol. But, I got it to work! I just decoded it, targeted those values in the array/object mess, and encoded it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Use json_decode to get an array you normally use. 

`$array = json_decode($data['methods']);`